# Why doesn't my interpolation result in qgis look good?

Tags: qgis, error, interpolation

My goal is to use some RTK GPS data from combines or sprayers to generate an interpolated DEM of fields for agricultural purposes. I used QGIS for that. So far I opened the data and did a simple TIN interpolation with the interpolation tool in the raster drop-down. As input, I took the point layer and as the attribute the elevation. Somehow the result always looked like that:
[image: interpolation result of the TIN interpolation]

Does anyone know why it doesn't work? I did the same steps as in the qgis tutorial about interpolating point data.

here is a part of the sample point attribute table:

[image]

Comment: Is the source point layer CRS defined as a projected or geographic coordinate system?

Comment: Would be great to post some rows of xyz values to check a sample data

Comment: The source Layer is projected in WGS 84, which was the default.

Comment: And what is also worth mentioning it, the IDW worked perfectly fine but doesn't really fulfil the purpose on elevation data

Comment: Do you mean from the attribute table of the sample points? @aldo_tapia

Comment: @M.Altenbach yes

Comment: @aldo_tapia I got a screenshot of the attribute table in the post, does that help?

Comment: In my opinion, I think that WGS 84 is not the proper CRS to work with for this case. Project to a CRS in the measurement unit (meter or feet). You have a densely populated data set with submillimeter z values from an herbicide application... I suspect that come from a tractor (I'm right?)... But, are enough accurate to this precision? I would clean some data before TIN creation, maybe is one solution. Also, did you try [this approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150291/creating-tin-from-elevation-points-in-qgis)?

Comment: @aldo_tapia Yes, you are right, it is from a sprayer operation. I might try reprojecting the data first. I haven't tried the other approach yet, maybe this helps. I'll let you know.

Comment: @M.Altenbach how does the QGIS heat map layer renderer look on the point layer?

Comment: Can you open an issue on hub.qgis.org and share some data? I'd like to look into this.

Comment: I will give a try to `v.surf.idw` from the GRASS Processing Toolbox

Comment: @DPSSpatial I tried the heatmap, but that didn't look very well.

Comment: @ndawson I created an Issue on the qgis hub. It's issue #17374. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: @Marco unfortunately that didn't work either, result is just a blank map

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I finally got it. I always had projection issues, changing all the projections to UTM finally helped. Thanks for your help.