# Volume calculation of CSV file

Tags: qgis, csv, point-cloud

I have a CSV file with point cloud data of a terrain.
How do I use QGIS to calculate the volume of the terrain?

I tried using SAGA tool, natural neighbour, then use raster volume calculation.
However, I am pretty skeptical about the result.

I think the parameters in natural neighbour has not been set correctly. Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: May be this will help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150314/87346

Answer (score 1):

> I think the parameters in natural neighbour has not been set correctly.

The parameters in the natural neighbor are not usually a problem, the default *Method* and *Fit* values give good results in most cases.

What is important is that you do not compute the volume outside the contour of the terrain.
Make sure to *Clip Raster by Mask Layer* before computing the volume.

> Can anyone advise me on this?

Use the *TIN Interpolation* instead. Draw the break lines in a vector layer and add them to the procedure. Rarely does a land have no break lines.